# Can I do UV imaging from my mobile camera?

Tags: uv

I want to know that can my mobile phone Mi-A1 or Nokia mobile 6.1 can capture a photo from a light source which is 340-350nm. I am illuminating my object with 280nm light, followed by fluorescence of object that emits 340nm. And want to capture an image with this wavelength(340nm).

please kindly help me with your suggestions.
will my mobile camera work for this capture?

Comment: Solid state image sensors such as that in your phone have a sensitivity range that extends both into the IR and UV. The problem will be with the optics. From Wikipedia "Most types of glass will allow longwave UV to pass, but absorb all the other UV wavelengths, usually from about 350 nm and below. For UV photography it is necessary to use specially developed lenses having elements made from fused quartz or quartz and fluorite."

Answer (score 3):

Although the sensors may be sensitive to non-visible wavelengths, **no generally available consumer camera will reliably capture light outside of the visible spectrum** because filters are placed in front of the sensor to prevent non-visible wavelengths from interfering with the cameras' primary purpose, which is to capture visible light. If you want to capture non-visible wavelengths, **you will need to modify your camera/phone** by replacing the hot-mirror filter with a different filter that will pass through the wavelengths you are interested in.

If you do not wish to modify any of your existing equipment, you can find already modified gear by searching for "full spectrum camera" on your favorite auction site.